# visual response for Functions in another file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, electron

I´m a beginner in Javascript and have a problem for a while. First to the case:

i´m building an electron Deskotp application, which is connected to a mySQL database. 
In the main.js i connect via sequelize, which works fine. 
What i want now is, the landingpage (index.html) should show a svg with a green circle if the connection is successful, and a red one when electron is not connected to the database. 
code main.js:

```
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'example',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database'
});
connection.connect();
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://example:password:localhost/database');

sequelize

  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection successfully made.');

  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');

  });
```

index.html:

```
<text class="titel"> Statusanzeige </text>

   <div class="connection" id="connection"><svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <g transform="matrix(1.04747,0,0,1.04747,4.75659,4.03844)">
        <text x="21.032px" y="13.026px" style="font-family:'ArialMT', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:16px;fill:white;"> mit Datenbank verbunden</text>
    </g>

    <g transform="matrix(1.05652,0,0,1.18757,0.119163,-1.87565)">
        <ellipse cx="12.963" cy="10" rx="8.519" ry="7.579" style="fill:rgb(78, 246, 0);"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

what i don´t understand is, how can i toggle two differrent svg´s in case of .then and .catch in the index.html?

maybe an example with explanation would great, i still have a view understanding problems.

thank you for your time!

Comment: Why not have one SVG and toggle the colour via setAttribute.

Comment: i had this idea also, but my problem is the same, i don´t know how to give the value of sequelize to the html file and do this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert says, just change the colour of the circle using CSS.

Something like the following:

```
const connState = document.getElementById("connection-state");

sequelize

  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection successfully made.');
    connState.classList.add("connected");
    connState.classList.remove("not-connected");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');
    connState.classList.add("not-connected");
    connState.classList.remove("connected");
  });
```

```
<div class="connection" id="connection">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <g transform="matrix(1.04747,0,0,1.04747,4.75659,4.03844)">
        <text x="21.032px" y="13.026px" style="font-family:'ArialMT', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size:16px;fill:white;"> mit Datenbank verbunden</text>
    </g>

    <g transform="matrix(1.05652,0,0,1.18757,0.119163,-1.87565)">
      <ellipse id="connection-state" cx="12.963" cy="10" rx="8.519" ry="7.579"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

</div>
```

```
#connection-state {
  fill: grey;
}

#connection-state.connected {
  fill: rgb(78, 246, 0);
}

#connection-state.not-connected {
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response! if i try it with connState.classList i got the following error:  Cannot read property 'classList' of null.  is it possible this is a problem with electron? i already added jsdom to work with DOM. so seems like electron is a bit different then web.

Comment: Possibly. It could also be when you call that code. The DOM needs to be ready before you try and update it.  So either wait for the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) before you call `getElementById()`. Or you could try moving that line inside the `then` and `catch` blocks.